# iisnode: Unknown stdin file type

Tags: windows, node.js, stdin, iisnode

I have iisnode working smoothly on win8/IIS8. I created a very simple hello world and it works great. However, when I try to use process.stdin I get the following error:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.startup.processStdio.process.openStdin [as stdin] (node.js:405:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ApprendaPlatform\SiteData\developer\v1\root\shim\node_modules\actionhero\bin\zzz.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

Note that I do not get this with process.stdout.

My code:

```
// kaboom!
var breakthings = process.stdin;

// works
// var breakthings = process.stdout;
```

Is iisnode doing something funky to stdin, or have I misconfigured something?

Comment: Just in case anyone else encounters this:  
  
This appears to be a bug in iisnode. The github issue is here:  
  
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/337  
  
Node uses process.stdin to gather input from the console. Since there's no console in play with iisnode, that object isn't necessary. As a workaround, wrap any block that uses process.stdin with something like so:  

    if(!process.env.IISNODE_VERSION) {
    // do stuff with process.stdin
    }

Answer (score 1):

In my case, and since the issue still occurs, I just override the getter from the process.stdin in the iisnode file

```
var events = require('events');

// Define a custom getter for process.stdin since iisnode still didn't fix the bug
process.__defineGetter__('stdin', function(){
    return new events.EventEmitter();
})

// no kaboom anymore ;)
var breakthings = process.stdin;
```

hope this help ;)

UPDATE (02-06-2016):
In a more advisable and clean way:

```
var events = require('events');

delete process.stdin;
process.stdin = new events.EventEmitter();

// no kaboom anymore ;)
var breakthings = process.stdin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actionhero now has a check for this kind of thing https://github.com/evantahler/actionhero/commit/465a85fba9800466ab9ca3d5df65a18f7decd830