# 'Unknown stdin file type' error in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

I've been struggling with this errors for 2 days and can't realize why electron renderer `process.stdin` fails in windows os.

How to reproduce:

type `npm install devtool -g` 
then type `devtool` 
inside the console type `process.stdin` and there will be an error message <strike>will be two errors, one at line 127 and the other at line 128 at C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\atom.asar\renderer\lib\init.js</strike>(devtool update 2.x)

`Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!`

`C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resour…:127 Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!(…)(anonymous function) @ C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resour…:127Module._compile @ module.js:425Module._extensions..js @ module.js:432Module.load @ module.js:356Module._load @ module.js:313Module.runMain @ module.js:457startup @ node.js:151(anonymous function) @ node.js:1007
C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resour…:128 Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.stdin (node.js:747)
    at hookProcess (C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\lib\preload.js:117)
    at C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\lib\preload.js:29
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\lib\preload.js:129)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432)
    at Module.load (module.js:356)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313)
    at Module.require (module.js:366)
    at require (module.js:385)(anonymous function) @ C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\devtool\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resour…:128Module._compile @ module.js:425Module._extensions..js @ module.js:432Module.load @ module.js:356Module._load @ module.js:313Module.runMain @ module.js:457startup @ node.js:151(anonymous function) @ node.js:1007`

Comment: Are you using the standard Windows command line shell, cmd.exe?

Comment: I've tried the prompt, git bash and powershell ...

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem.

First I thought that devtool as REPL does not need stdin and was a simple bug in windows build. GitHub repo owners fix it just ignoring stdin on startup but, as you had discovered, devtool is broken and you can not do anything with stdin in windows.

As a proof of concept I create a simple example beyond devtool REPL:

This piece of code does not work.

```
//test.js
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: true
});

rl.on('line', function(line){
    console.log(line);
})
```

> devtool test.js < input.txt

```
Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
```

Windows 7 x64, S.O. Admin rights, Node v5.10.0, npm v3.8.3 DevTool v1.9.1.

I had left a comment in your github [issue](https://github.com/Jam3/devtool/issues/42#) but is closed so I opened a [new one](https://github.com/Jam3/devtool/issues/58).

Comment: since devtool 2.x you need to type `process.stdin` in the console to see the error.

Comment: It certainly is windows related since it doesn't happen in other OS ... I really think the problem is in electron

Answer (score 1):

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281098/iisnode-unknown-stdin-file-type) pointing to the same problem. One of the comments states that it's a [known `iisnode` issue](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/337) and also suggests a work around by wrapping all calls to `process.stdin` like:

```
if(!process.env.IISNODE_VERSION) { 
    // do stuff with process.stdin 
}
```

It can be a temporary solution. I'm sure you've already taken a look to that post, what do you think?

Comment: Iisnode is hosting nodejs in iis. I do not think is related.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [libuv source code](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/win/handle.c#L31) which is what nodejs uses for certain low-level operations, seems that the reason is that the type of buffer or handle cannot be determined specifically for windows. The [`GetFileType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960(v=vs.85).aspx) function seems to return an unknown handle.

This is definitely a windows only issue because the part of the library that determines the type of handle is within `src/win/handle.c` of the UV source code so I don't think this affects *NIX OS'es indeed.

Maybe the installed nodejs version is missing a build-time option?

Comment: I also ended up at the 'handle.c' file and I'm still searching for a way to make it work on windows

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto well the thing is that GetFileType which is what they rely on to give the handle type is a Microsoft OS function which returns an unknown handle, I'm not an expert in that area but that leads me to think that the fix is outside a simple hack in your JS code unfortunately... maybe opening an issue in nodejs bugtracker?

Comment: Can I ask why do you need it on windows? Just curious, why not build it on a VirtualMachine or something? Worst case scenario you could try cygwin although I'm not sure how hard it'll be to build nodejs within a cygwin environment.

Comment: I don't need at all, I crossed with this problem solving an issue here in SO. I really just want to make the module to work on any OS properly.

Answer (score 1):

A super simple workaround would be to just force devtool to run in its own console window.

So instead of running:

```
devtool
```

Run this:

```
start devtool
```

It should pop up in a new window and not be confused about the input pipe.

The same trick works with a lot of Node packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error when trying to start electron up from a console window; it was odd because it had been working fine. I have realised today that the only thing I changed was to launch a terminal window from Visual Studio Code (with add-on).

If I use a Terminal created from VS Code (terminal addon) then when I try to run `node_modules\.bin\electron` I get:

```
d:\Code\Applications\Example>"node_modules\.bin\electron"
internal/process/stdio.js:86
        throw new Error('Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!');
        ^

Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.stdin (internal/process/stdio.js:86:15)
    at startup (node.js:198:18)
    at node.js:457:3
```

if I make a console window directly in Explorer, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: how do you "make a console window directly in Explorer" ?

Comment: Plz notice that the error appears in the electron window console, not in the prompt itself.